# What does a bar mean in matrices?

Tags: matrices, anova

This might be a really basic question but I'm calculating ANOVA tables for tables of design points and one of the calculations I need to do is: $Y^TY-N\bar{y}^2$ and I'm not sure what $\bar{y}$ means.

$Y$ is the matrix: $\begin {pmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
-1 \\
1 \\
-1
\end{pmatrix}$

$N$ is given to me in the question and I know $Y^T$ is the transpose of $Y$, I'm just not sure what $\bar{y}$ is, if anyone can let me know it would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The mean of all entries maybe? Does that make sense in the context?

Comment: Your question is weird, but "bar y" is denoting the mean of the "y observations" (this is very common notation). The "bar" is not on a "matrix" (although, the $y$ in $\bar y$ simply tries to convey that this is the $y$-variable, a.k.a. response, output, endogenous, etc.)

Comment: Sorry about the format/general-ness of my question, I know it's quite broad, I probably should have given some better context but regardless I think you're both right, I completely forgot that the mean can be represented using the bar. In my lecture notes for some reason my lecturer likes to actually write $mean$ rather than use the bar, that's probably why I forgot about it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it means the mean value of variable $y$. $\bar y =\frac 1N\sum_i y_i$. $y_i$ means the i th element in your vector $Y$

I think your formula $Y^TY - N\bar y^2$ is calculating the total sum of squares of $y$ right (
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_sums_of_squares)
$$
Y^TY - N\bar y^2 = \sum_i y_i^2 - N \bar y^2 = \sum_i(y_i^2 - \bar y ^2) = \sum_i(y_i - \bar y )^2 
$$

Comment: Yeah I think you're right, I completely forgot that the bar can be used to represent the mean of a variable. Thanks a lot